# How to activate fullscreen on custom video player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a basic video player, but when you toggle fullscreen then it goes into full screen, but it doesn't fill the screen.

I have googled for a solution but nothing has helped. I have even tried `.fullscreen{width:100%}`, but nothing has changed.

html

```
<div class='player-container'>
    <div class='galaxy-player'>
    <video id='video' src='../videoplayer/red.mp4' autoplay playsinline></video>
        <div class='play-btn-big'></div>
        <div class='controls'>
            <div class="time"><span class="time-current"></span><span class="time-total"></span></div>
            <div class='progress'>
                <div class='progress-filled'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='controls-main'>
                <div class='controls-left'>
                    <div class='volume'>
                        <div class='volume-btn loud'>
                            <svg width="26" height="24" viewBox="0 0 26 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M6.75497 17.6928H2C0.89543 17.6928 0 16.7973 0 15.6928V8.30611C0 7.20152 0.895431 6.30611 2 6.30611H6.75504L13.9555 0.237289C14.6058 -0.310807 15.6 0.151473 15.6 1.00191V22.997C15.6 23.8475 14.6058 24.3098 13.9555 23.7617L6.75497 17.6928Z" transform="translate(0 0.000518799)" fill="white"/>
                                <path id="volume-low" d="M0 9.87787C2.87188 9.87787 5.2 7.66663 5.2 4.93893C5.2 2.21124 2.87188 0 0 0V2C1.86563 2 3.2 3.41162 3.2 4.93893C3.2 6.46625 1.86563 7.87787 0 7.87787V9.87787Z" transform="translate(17.3333 7.44955)" fill="white"/>

                                <path id="volume-high" d="M0 16.4631C4.78647 16.4631 8.66667 12.7777 8.66667 8.23157C8.66667 3.68539 4.78647 0 0 0V2C3.78022 2 6.66667 4.88577 6.66667 8.23157C6.66667 11.5773 3.78022 14.4631 0 14.4631V16.4631Z" transform="translate(17.3333 4.15689)" fill="white"/> 
                        <path id="volume-off" d="M1.22565 0L0 1.16412L3.06413 4.0744L0 6.98471L1.22565 8.14883L4.28978 5.23853L7.35391 8.14883L8.57956 6.98471L5.51544 4.0744L8.57956 1.16412L7.35391 0L4.28978 2.91031L1.22565 0Z" transform="translate(17.3769 8.31403)" fill="white"/>
                            </svg>

                        </div>
                        <div class='volume-slider'>
                            <div class='volume-filled'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='play-btn paused'></div>
                <div class="controls-right">
                    <div class='speed'>
                        <ul class='speed-list'>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='0.5'>0.5x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='0.75'>0.75x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='1' class='active'>1x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='1.5'>1.5x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='2'>2x</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='fullscreen'>
                        <svg width="30" height="22" viewBox="0 0 30 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0V-1.5H-1.5V0H0ZM0 18H-1.5V19.5H0V18ZM26 18V19.5H27.5V18H26ZM26 0H27.5V-1.5H26V0ZM1.5 6.54545V0H-1.5V6.54545H1.5ZM0 1.5H10.1111V-1.5H0V1.5ZM-1.5 11.4545V18H1.5V11.4545H-1.5ZM0 19.5H10.1111V16.5H0V19.5ZM24.5 11.4545V18H27.5V11.4545H24.5ZM26 16.5H15.8889V19.5H26V16.5ZM27.5 6.54545V0H24.5V6.54545H27.5ZM26 -1.5H15.8889V1.5H26V-1.5Z" transform="translate(2 2)" fill="white"/>
    </svg>

    </svg>


    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.player-container {
    color: #fff;
    background: #191919;
margin: -17px 0 40px;
padding: 15px 0;
height: 950px;


}
.galaxy-player {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.galaxy-player:fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.galaxy-player:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.galaxy-player:-moz-full-screen {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.galaxy-player:-ms-fullscreen  {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
}
.galaxy-player video {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 200px;
/*     height: auto; */
/*     position: absolute; */
/*     top: 50%; */
/*     transform: translateY(-50%); */
  display: block;
}

.controls {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 263px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(37, 37, 37, 0) 10%,rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.6) 80%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in 5s;
}
.galaxy-player video:fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player .controls:fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player video:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player .controls:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player video:-moz-full-screen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player .controls:-moz-full-screen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player video:-ms-fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.galaxy-player .controls:-ms-fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
}
.player:hover .controls {
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.time {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.progress {
    height: 8px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: height 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.progress:hover {
    height: 10px;
}
.progress-filled {
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: all 0.1s; 
}
.controls-main {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.controls-left,
.controls-right {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.controls-left {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.controls-right {
    margin-right: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.volume {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.volume-btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.volume-btn #volume-off, .volume-btn #volume-high {
    opacity: 0;
}
.volume-btn.loud #volume-high{
    opacity: 1;
}
.volume-btn.muted #volume-off {
    opacity: 1;
}
.volume-btn.muted #volume-high, .volume-btn.muted #volume-low {
    opacity: 0;
}
.volume-slider {
    height: 8px;
    width: 80px;
    background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
.volume-filled {
    background: var(--main);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.volume-filled:hover, .play-btn:hover.play-btn:before, .play-btn:hover.play-btn:after{
    background: var(--accent);
}
button {
}
.play-btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    transition: -webkit-clip-path 0.3s ease-in 0.1s, shape-inside 0.3s ease-in 0.1s,
        transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.85, -0.25, 0.25, 1.425);
}
.play-btn.paused {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.play-btn:before,
.play-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: inherit;
}
.play-btn:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 40%, 0 40%);
    shape-inside: polygon(0 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 40%, 0 40%);
}
.play-btn:after {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 100% 60%, 100% 90%, 0 90%);
    shape-inside: polygon(0 60%, 100% 60%, 100% 90%, 0 90%);
}
.play-btn.paused:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 90% 51%, 90% 51%, 10% 51%);
    shape-inside: polygon(0 0, 100% 51%, 100% 51%, 0 51%);
}
.play-btn.paused:after {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 49.5%, 80% 49.5%, 90% 49.5%, 10% 100%);
    shape-inside: polygon(10% 49.5%, 80% 49.5%, 90% 49.5%, 10% 100%);
}
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.speed-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.speed-list li {
    color: var(--main);
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: default;
}
.speed-list li:hover,
.speed-list li.active {
    color: var(--accent);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fullscreen {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Javascript

```
//ELEMENT SELECTORS
var player = document.querySelector('.galaxy-player');
var video = document.querySelector('#video');
var playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
var volumeBtn = document.querySelector('.volume-btn');
var volumeSlider = document.querySelector('.volume-slider');
var volumeFill = document.querySelector('.volume-filled');
var progressSlider = document.querySelector('.progress');
var progressFill = document.querySelector('.progress-filled');
var textCurrent = document.querySelector('.time-current');
var textTotal = document.querySelector('.time-total');
var speedBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.speed-item');
var fullscreenBtn =document.querySelector('.fullscreen'); 

//GLOBAL VARS
let lastVolume = 1;
let isMouseDown = false;

//PLAYER FUNCTIONS
function togglePlay() {
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();  
    }
    playBtn.classList.toggle('paused');
}
function togglePlayBtn() {
    playBtn.classList.toggle('playing');
}

function toggleMute() {
    if(video.volume) {
        lastVolume = video.volume;
        video.volume = 0;
        volumeBtn.classList.add('muted');
        volumeFill.style.width = 0;
    } else {
        video.volume = lastVolume;
        volumeBtn.classList.remove('muted');
        volumeFill.style.width = `${lastVolume*100}%`;
    }
}
function changeVolume(e) {
        volumeBtn.classList.remove('muted');
        let volume = e.offsetX/volumeSlider.offsetWidth;
        volume<0.1 ? volume = 0 : volume=volume; 
        volumeFill.style.width = `${volume*100}%`;
        video.volume = volume;
        if (volume > 0.7) {
            volumeBtn.classList.add('loud');
        } else if (volume < 0.7 && volume > 0) {
            volumeBtn.classList.remove('loud');
        } else if (volume == 0) {
            volumeBtn.classList.add('muted');
        }
        lastVolume = volume;
}
function neatTime(time) {
  // var hours = Math.floor((time % 86400)/3600)
  var minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600)/60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
    seconds = seconds>9?seconds:`0${seconds}`;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
function updateProgress(e) {
    progressFill.style.width = `${video.currentTime/video.duration*100}%`;
    textCurrent.innerHTML = `${neatTime(video.currentTime)} / ${neatTime(video.duration)}`;
    // textTotal.innerHTML = neatTime(video.duration);
    // console.log(progressFill.style.width);
}
function setProgress(e) {
    const newTime = e.offsetX/progressSlider.offsetWidth;
    progressFill.style.width = `${newTime*100}%`;
    video.currentTime = newTime*video.duration;
}
function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
function exitFullscreen() {
  if(document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}
var fullscreen = false;
function toggleFullscreen() {
    fullscreen? exitFullscreen() : launchIntoFullscreen(player)
    fullscreen = !fullscreen;
}
function setSpeed(e) {
    console.log(parseFloat(this.dataset.speed));
    video.playbackRate = this.dataset.speed;
    speedBtns.forEach(speedBtn =>   speedBtn.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
}
function handleKeypress(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case " ":
            togglePlay();
        case "ArrowRight":
            video.currentTime += 5;
        case "ArrowLeft":
            video.currentTime -= 5;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
//EVENT LISTENERS
playBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('play', togglePlayBtn);
video.addEventListener('pause', togglePlayBtn);
video.addEventListener('ended', togglePlayBtn);
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);
video.addEventListener('canplay', updateProgress);
volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMute);
window.addEventListener('mousedown', () => isMouseDown = true)
window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isMouseDown = false)
// volumeSlider.addEventListener('mouseover', changeVolume);
volumeSlider.addEventListener('click', changeVolume);
progressSlider.addEventListener('click', setProgress);
fullscreenBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFullscreen);
speedBtns.forEach(speedBtn => {
    speedBtn.addEventListener('click', setSpeed);
})
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeypress);
```

Here is a screenshot of the fullscreen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSzSI.jpg

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

P.S Video used is for placeholder references only.

Answer (score 0):

### Add flex and give the galaxy-player the width control

I add some changing to your code.

Tell me if its ok for you :)

```js
//ELEMENT SELECTORS
var player = document.querySelector('.galaxy-player');
var video = document.querySelector('#video');
var playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
var volumeBtn = document.querySelector('.volume-btn');
var volumeSlider = document.querySelector('.volume-slider');
var volumeFill = document.querySelector('.volume-filled');
var progressSlider = document.querySelector('.progress');
var progressFill = document.querySelector('.progress-filled');
var textCurrent = document.querySelector('.time-current');
var textTotal = document.querySelector('.time-total');
var speedBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.speed-item');
var fullscreenBtn =document.querySelector('.fullscreen'); 

//GLOBAL VARS
let lastVolume = 1;
let isMouseDown = false;

//PLAYER FUNCTIONS
function togglePlay() {
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();  
    }
    playBtn.classList.toggle('paused');
}
function togglePlayBtn() {
    playBtn.classList.toggle('playing');
}

function toggleMute() {
    if(video.volume) {
        lastVolume = video.volume;
        video.volume = 0;
        volumeBtn.classList.add('muted');
        volumeFill.style.width = 0;
    } else {
        video.volume = lastVolume;
        volumeBtn.classList.remove('muted');
        volumeFill.style.width = `${lastVolume*100}%`;
    }
}
function changeVolume(e) {
        volumeBtn.classList.remove('muted');
        let volume = e.offsetX/volumeSlider.offsetWidth;
        volume<0.1 ? volume = 0 : volume=volume; 
        volumeFill.style.width = `${volume*100}%`;
        video.volume = volume;
        if (volume > 0.7) {
            volumeBtn.classList.add('loud');
        } else if (volume < 0.7 && volume > 0) {
            volumeBtn.classList.remove('loud');
        } else if (volume == 0) {
            volumeBtn.classList.add('muted');
        }
        lastVolume = volume;
}
function neatTime(time) {
  // var hours = Math.floor((time % 86400)/3600)
  var minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600)/60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
    seconds = seconds>9?seconds:`0${seconds}`;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
function updateProgress(e) {
    progressFill.style.width = `${video.currentTime/video.duration*100}%`;
    textCurrent.innerHTML = `${neatTime(video.currentTime)} / ${neatTime(video.duration)}`;
    // textTotal.innerHTML = neatTime(video.duration);
    // console.log(progressFill.style.width);
}
function setProgress(e) {
    const newTime = e.offsetX/progressSlider.offsetWidth;
    progressFill.style.width = `${newTime*100}%`;
    video.currentTime = newTime*video.duration;
}
function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
  console.log(element)
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
function exitFullscreen() {
  if(document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}
var fullscreen = false;
function toggleFullscreen() {
    fullscreen? exitFullscreen() : launchIntoFullscreen(player)
    fullscreen = !fullscreen;
}
function setSpeed(e) {
    console.log(parseFloat(this.dataset.speed));
    video.playbackRate = this.dataset.speed;
    speedBtns.forEach(speedBtn =>   speedBtn.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
}
function handleKeypress(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case " ":
            togglePlay();
        case "ArrowRight":
            video.currentTime += 5;
        case "ArrowLeft":
            video.currentTime -= 5;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
//EVENT LISTENERS
playBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('play', togglePlayBtn);
video.addEventListener('pause', togglePlayBtn);
video.addEventListener('ended', togglePlayBtn);
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);
video.addEventListener('canplay', updateProgress);
volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMute);
window.addEventListener('mousedown', () => isMouseDown = true)
window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isMouseDown = false)
// volumeSlider.addEventListener('mouseover', changeVolume);
volumeSlider.addEventListener('click', changeVolume);
progressSlider.addEventListener('click', setProgress);
fullscreenBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFullscreen);
speedBtns.forEach(speedBtn => {
    speedBtn.addEventListener('click', setSpeed);
})
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeypress);
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.player-container {
    color: #fff;
    background: #191919;
/*     margin: -17px 0 40px; */
/*     padding: 15px 0; */
/*     height: 950px; */
    height: 100%;
}
.galaxy-player {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.galaxy-player:fullscreen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.galaxy-player:-webkit-full-screen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.galaxy-player:-moz-full-screen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.galaxy-player:-ms-fullscreen  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
}
.galaxy-player video {
    width: 100%;
/*     height: auto; */
/*     position: absolute; */
/*     top: 50%; */
/*     transform: translateY(-50%); */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.controls {
  margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        rgba(37, 37, 37, 0) 10%,
        rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.6) 80%
    );
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in 5s;
}
.galaxy-player:fullscreen video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}
.galaxy-player:fullscreen .controls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galaxy-player:-webkit-full-screen video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}
.galaxy-player:-webkit-full-screen .controls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galaxy-player:-moz-full-screen video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}
.galaxy-player:-moz-full-screen .controls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galaxy-player:-ms-fullscreen video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}
.galaxy-player:-ms-fullscreen .controls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.player:hover .controls {
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.time {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.progress {
    height: 8px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: height 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.progress:hover {
    height: 10px;
}
.progress-filled {
    background: var(--accent);
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: all 0.1s; 
}
.controls-main {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.controls-left,
.controls-right {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.controls-left {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.controls-right {
    margin-right: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.volume {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.volume-btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.volume-btn #volume-off, .volume-btn #volume-high {
    opacity: 0;
}
.volume-btn.loud #volume-high{
    opacity: 1;
}
.volume-btn.muted #volume-off {
    opacity: 1;
}
.volume-btn.muted #volume-high, .volume-btn.muted #volume-low {
    opacity: 0;
}
.volume-slider {
    height: 8px;
    width: 80px;
    background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
.volume-filled {
    background: var(--main);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.volume-filled:hover, .play-btn:hover.play-btn:before, .play-btn:hover.play-btn:after{
    background: var(--accent);
}
button {
}
.play-btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    transition: -webkit-clip-path 0.3s ease-in 0.1s, shape-inside 0.3s ease-in 0.1s,
        transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.85, -0.25, 0.25, 1.425);
}
.play-btn.paused {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.play-btn:before,
.play-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: inherit;
}
.play-btn:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 40%, 0 40%);
    shape-inside: polygon(0 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 40%, 0 40%);
}
.play-btn:after {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 100% 60%, 100% 90%, 0 90%);
    shape-inside: polygon(0 60%, 100% 60%, 100% 90%, 0 90%);
}
.play-btn.paused:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 90% 51%, 90% 51%, 10% 51%);
    shape-inside: polygon(0 0, 100% 51%, 100% 51%, 0 51%);
}
.play-btn.paused:after {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 49.5%, 80% 49.5%, 90% 49.5%, 10% 100%);
    shape-inside: polygon(10% 49.5%, 80% 49.5%, 90% 49.5%, 10% 100%);
}
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.speed-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.speed-list li {
    color: var(--main);
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: default;
}
.speed-list li:hover,
.speed-list li.active {
    color: var(--accent);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fullscreen {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='player-container'>
    <div class='galaxy-player'>
    <video id='video' src='../videoplayer/red.mp4' autoplay playsinline></video>
        <div class='play-btn-big'></div>
        <div class='controls'>
            <div class="time"><span class="time-current"></span><span class="time-total"></span></div>
            <div class='progress'>
                <div class='progress-filled'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='controls-main'>
                <div class='controls-left'>
                    <div class='volume'>
                        <div class='volume-btn loud'>
                            <svg width="26" height="24" viewBox="0 0 26 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M6.75497 17.6928H2C0.89543 17.6928 0 16.7973 0 15.6928V8.30611C0 7.20152 0.895431 6.30611 2 6.30611H6.75504L13.9555 0.237289C14.6058 -0.310807 15.6 0.151473 15.6 1.00191V22.997C15.6 23.8475 14.6058 24.3098 13.9555 23.7617L6.75497 17.6928Z" transform="translate(0 0.000518799)" fill="white"/>
                                <path id="volume-low" d="M0 9.87787C2.87188 9.87787 5.2 7.66663 5.2 4.93893C5.2 2.21124 2.87188 0 0 0V2C1.86563 2 3.2 3.41162 3.2 4.93893C3.2 6.46625 1.86563 7.87787 0 7.87787V9.87787Z" transform="translate(17.3333 7.44955)" fill="white"/>

                                <path id="volume-high" d="M0 16.4631C4.78647 16.4631 8.66667 12.7777 8.66667 8.23157C8.66667 3.68539 4.78647 0 0 0V2C3.78022 2 6.66667 4.88577 6.66667 8.23157C6.66667 11.5773 3.78022 14.4631 0 14.4631V16.4631Z" transform="translate(17.3333 4.15689)" fill="white"/> 
                        <path id="volume-off" d="M1.22565 0L0 1.16412L3.06413 4.0744L0 6.98471L1.22565 8.14883L4.28978 5.23853L7.35391 8.14883L8.57956 6.98471L5.51544 4.0744L8.57956 1.16412L7.35391 0L4.28978 2.91031L1.22565 0Z" transform="translate(17.3769 8.31403)" fill="white"/>
                            </svg>

                        </div>
                        <div class='volume-slider'>
                            <div class='volume-filled'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='play-btn paused'></div>
                <div class="controls-right">
                    <div class='speed'>
                        <ul class='speed-list'>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='0.5'>0.5x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='0.75'>0.75x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='1' class='active'>1x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='1.5'>1.5x</li>
                            <li class='speed-item' data-speed='2'>2x</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='fullscreen'>
                        <svg width="30" height="22" viewBox="0 0 30 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0V-1.5H-1.5V0H0ZM0 18H-1.5V19.5H0V18ZM26 18V19.5H27.5V18H26ZM26 0H27.5V-1.5H26V0ZM1.5 6.54545V0H-1.5V6.54545H1.5ZM0 1.5H10.1111V-1.5H0V1.5ZM-1.5 11.4545V18H1.5V11.4545H-1.5ZM0 19.5H10.1111V16.5H0V19.5ZM24.5 11.4545V18H27.5V11.4545H24.5ZM26 16.5H15.8889V19.5H26V16.5ZM27.5 6.54545V0H24.5V6.54545H27.5ZM26 -1.5H15.8889V1.5H26V-1.5Z" transform="translate(2 2)" fill="white"/>
    </svg>

    </svg>


    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you full screen is now working but how do i get the controls to be full width and at the bottom of the full screen only https://imgur.com/HKTSN2b

Comment: In my example the controls are 100% width. mm can I see your code now?

Comment: Ok, so update it to what I wrote in my answer. for instane In the controls I put in comment the ` position: absolute;`

Comment: I have done that but now it is too close to the navigation bar and if i use margin-top of even padding-top then it messes up the full screen also i want the controls to be on the video and not below it, but when i change that then it also messes up full screen mode :/ https://imgur.com/qknIzJb

Comment: I edit, look and tell me if it is ok. I put the video on 100% height also, not sure that is what you want.